# update the owner on content delivery via dataloader?

Tags: force.com, content, content-delivery

I'm new to the content world, and my new company uses it heavily. I'm having a problem querying some of the fields. On the content delivery there is a checkbox called "Content Delivery Opens Latest Version" and  the owner field. I want to update both of those. The object's prefix is '05D'

1. Can i update these fields
2. where do I access them (what object name?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the Content Delivery object isn't available via the API. There is an idea about that -- go vote it up! https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000KaQoAAK